# SQL Server Management Studio - Xamarin

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am using Xamarin to create a cross platform app (Xamarin.Forms), I am storing all my data in a server inside SQL Server 2016. I am not allowed to use web services. But I want to connect the database to the project and would like to carry on some operations to the data in it.

The main problem - I don't know how to connect them. I have the local database connection line in my app.xaml.cs like this -

```
database = new UserDatabase(DependencyService.Get<ILocalFileHelper>().GetFilePatg("User.db3");
```

Now for the server I have the database server name (let's say "ABC"), how do i use that server name to replace this previous lime of code?

I am aware that people use `System.Data.SqlClient`. For some reason I don't have the `System.Data`. I can't seem to find it in references either (searching for the reference says that I have all the references).

Thank you

Comment: Why can't you have a web service between the database and your mobile apps?

Comment: I am working for a corporate business, it's just one if their requirements. They did however allow me to use LINQ, I don't know how to use that too. Searching online doesn't give the specific connection code.

Comment: You need to find out *why* that requirement exists, because it doesn't make sense and is likely based on some misplaced belief. It absolutely doesn't make sense to have apps directly hit the database, and you need to make that case. Make it clear that building such an application is far more risky and time consuming and fragile.

Comment: Also, what does this question have to do with SQL Server Management Studio?

Comment: If they are not ready to put up a web service then they are not ready to create a mobile app. Like mason said, they may have the wrong idea about what a web service actually is and possibly what types of authentication are available for it.

Comment: This is what I was told - they just want to do some very basic stuff with the app for the while being. As I am not an expert, they want something very easy for me.

Comment: Also this has everything to do with SQL Server Management Studio. I am connecting database that is over there.

Comment: The real back-end implementation will be done later on (with much secure sophistication).

Comment: SSMS is a client tool you use to manage a SQL Server Database.  It has nothing to do with the interaction between another client and the db server.